# Pass a variable from child to parent component

Tags: angular

So I am trying to get a value from my child component to print in my parent component and I tried the following:

In my child component ts:

```
export class ChildComponent  {
 message: string = 'Hello!!!'; 
}
```

In my parent component ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component'

 export class ShoppingCartComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit  {
  messageFromChild : string;
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) myChild;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.messageFromChild = this.myChild.message;
  }
  }
```

In my parent component html:

```
<h1> From Child - {{ messageFromChild }}  </h1>
```

{{ messageFromChild }} is blank.

The tutorial that I followed said to add the parent component to the bootstrap array in app.module.ts but when I did that I got a blank page.

In the console, I get the error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Comment: how you are passing the input from Parent..? will you show us the parent template code for better understanding of your problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `@Output` and `EventEmitter`

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class ChildComponent  {
@Output() message: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

Now inside any of your method/based on your logic in your child.component.ts, do

```
someMethod() {
this.message.emit('Hello');
}
```

Now, inside your parent component html,

`<app-child (message)="onMessageReceived($event)"> </app-child>`

and finally, inside parent ts,

```
onMessageReceived(message) {
console.log(message);
}
```

If your still facing issues, check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-output)